# Law of large numbers for arbitrarily dependent random variables

Tags: random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

Consider a sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$. No assumptions abou independence is made. Only joint probability density function is known, i.e. $f(x_1,...,x_n)$. Then [Markov's theorem](https://books.google.lt/books?id=cLCpDk1XrsIC&pg=PA199&lpg=PA199&dq=%22markov%20theorem%22%20law%20of%20large%20numbers&source=bl&ots=oDN6Z7p1ra&sig=6Du4Tjbv1PRfYEq_jIteG3gUY4k&hl=lt&sa=X&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAmoVChMIjbO5vaOMxwIViQwsCh0YNQ3T#v=onepage&q=%22markov%20theorem%22%20law%20of%20large%20numbers&f=false) states that for any constant $\epsilon>0$:
$$\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{lim} \mathbb{P}\{ \left | \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\textbf{E}X_k \right |<\epsilon  \}=1$$
if
$$\frac{1}{n^2}Var\left ( \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \right )\rightarrow 0.$$
This is a very general formulation of law of the large numbers. This formulation with arbitrary dependence structure can by found in other books as well. But I am interested in the classes of distributions or a model structure when the condition $\frac{1}{n^2}Var\left ( \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \right )\rightarrow 0$ does not hold.
For example does this condition fail for heavy tailed distributions? Does the distribution have to decay at certain rate at infinity? Or maybe it cannot have strong coorelations between too many variables? etc.

I could not find any source on this matter. Any information on this issue would be highly appreciated.

UPDATE

Variance of the sum i.e. $Var\left ( \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \right )$ is in fact simply the sum of all entries of the covariance matrix of random variables $X_1,...,X_n$. Denote this covariance matrix by $C$. In addition, denote by $e$ a vector with all entries being equal to 1. Then it is true that
$$Var\left ( \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \right )=e^T C e$$
We have also the following bound for the quadratic forms:
$$\lambda_{min} x^T x\leq x^T A x\leq \lambda_{max}x^Tx$$
Hence, with our notation we have that
$$n\lambda_{min}\leq Var\left ( \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \right )\leq n\lambda_{max},$$
and then deviding by $n^2$ and taking the limit:
$$0\leq lim \frac{1}{n^2}Var\left ( \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \right )\leq lim \frac{\lambda_{max}}{n}$$

And the question boils down to the question whether maximal eigenvalue stays bounded for the covariance matrix when the dimension grows.
Any suggestions how to attack this problem is welcome.

Comment: The only way this condition can fail is if the variance of each $X_k$ is growing in $k$ sufficiently fast, if it's not already infinite. It will fall for any distributions, fat-tail or heavy so long as the variance is infinite, like the Cauchy distribution.

Comment: Of course it fails for heavy tailed distributions with infinite variance...

Comment: But is the bounded variance is sufficient for the condition to hold?

Comment: If $X_n=X$ for all $n$, where $Var(X)=1$, then it fails (you said that you did not necessarily have independence).

Comment: @Tomas: No. In your sum, you will have $n$ varianece terms and around $n(n-1)/2$ covariance terms, which grows like $n^2$ and hence when divided by $n^2$ won't go to 0. You need "most" of the covariance terms to contribute much less.

Comment: @AlexR. Had a hunch abou this. But then basically the question boils down to the issue on the covariance structure or the structure of dependence. Probably it is not far from truth to guess that many of the covariance entries should be negative and many should be positive. Because if all entries are bounded from above and below by positive constants then that sum of $n(n-1)/2$ covariance terms will be bounded by the same constant at the limit and hence not zero.